# convert Table to List<Map<String,String>> conditional upon the value of the first column

Tags: java, string, list

Edit: Im limited to Java8 for now

i have a table which has always 3 columns: id | key | value

i can put this table in a `List<List<String>>` format (every row is a List of Strings) or a `List<String>` format (all table values in a List) very easy.
But my actual goal is a `List<Map<String,String>>` (or `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` see example) where the map contains the key-value pairs of my table and each list contains all key-value pairs for the same given id of my table

For example following table

```
| ID    | KEY   | VALUE     |
|----   |-----  |-------    |
| 1     | A     | X         |
| 1     | B     | Y         |
| 2     | C     | Z         |
| 3     | D     | BLA       |
```

should turn into

```
{
    ((A=X),(B=Y)),
    ((C=Z)),
    ((D=BLA)),
}
```

the ID Column is only needed for grouping

the ID can be anything from numeric to alphanumeric

i've come up with something that works, but its ugly and probably there is a way to do it better and more readable, maybe with streams?

```
    List<List<String>> myTable = something;
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (List<String> s: myTable ) {
        if (!outerMap.containsKey(s.get(0))) {
            innerMap.clear();
        }   
        innerMap.put(s.get(1), s.get(2));
        outerMap.put(s.get(0), new HashMap<>(innerMap));
    }
```

Note that i create the HashMap to put in outerMap way too often.

Comment: What exactly does your input data look like inside that `List<List<String>>`?

Comment: Why is this important? Can be anything really

Comment: I don't understand how that list stores the table you showed us. For that example, would it contain 3 lists, all of them containing the keys and values as seperate elemnts? So like this: `[["A", "X", "B", "Y"], ["C", "Z"], ["D," "BLA"]]`?

Comment: each row of the table is one List, and then a List, which contains this lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stream API for this.

First `groupingBy` ID for outer map then `toMap` by KEY VALUE for inner map

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> res = myTable.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.get(0),  
                      Collectors.toMap(f -> f.get(1),g -> g.get(2))));
```

And to get the only values of outer map

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>(res.values());
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow. I have my problems understanding the stream api, even i've read some articles about it now. What would be a good approach, learning to write this stuff myself?

Comment: This works. Thanks. How would i do it, when i want to throw the id away after grouping and put my Maps in a List<Map<String,String>> instead?

Comment: @Krwasch Easier way will be call `res.values()` and create a list ,  see the updated  answer.

Comment: @Krwasch There are many online resources available, just try to start.

Answer (score 0):

By using **Stream API:: forEach** like this

*Note*: `Map.of()` from JDK-9+

```
        myTable.forEach(row -> {
            outerMap.put(row.get(0), new HashMap<>(Map.of(row.get(1), row.get(2))));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as elegant as using streams, but maybe easier to understand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> myTable = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("1", "A", "X"), Arrays.asList("1", "B", "Y"),
            Arrays.asList("2", "C", "Z"), Arrays.asList("3", "D", "BLA"));

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (List<String> row : myTable) {
        String id = row.get(0);

        Map<String, String> map = result.get(id);
        if (map == null) {
            Map<String, String> entry = new HashMap<>();
            entry.put(row.get(1), row.get(2));
            result.put(id, entry);
        } else
            map.put(row.get(1), row.get(2));
    }
}
```